# Data is not being rendered albeit available in state

Tags: reactjs, rest, rendering

I'd like to ask you why is my React code acting so strange. Component class:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

class ReservationsTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          rows : []
      };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const tData = [];
    const userString = localStorage.getItem('user');
    const user = JSON.parse(userString);
    const reservationsProm = fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/reservations/', { method: 'get' }).then((res) => res.json());
    const reservations = await reservationsProm;
    const currentUserRes = reservations.filter((res) => res.client == user.id);
    currentUserRes.forEach(async (res) => {
      const url = `http://localhost:8000/api/books/${res.book}`;
      const book = await fetch(url);
         const bookData = await book.json();
         const sDate =  new Date(res.startDate).toDateString();
         const tDate = new Date(res.returnDate).toDateString();
         const displayObj = {
           title: bookData.title,
           from: sDate,
           to: tDate
         };
         tData.push(displayObj); 
    })
    this.setState({ rows: tData }, () => console.log(this.state.rows));
  }

  render() {
    const classes = makeStyles({
      table: {
        minWidth: 650,
      },
    });
    if (this.state.rows.length > 0){
    return ( 
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Your personal reservations</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Title</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">From&nbsp;</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">To&nbsp;</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          { this.state.rows.map((row) => (
            <TableRow key={row.title}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.title}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.from}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.to}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          )) }
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  )
  } else {
    return (
      <div> {`You have no active reservations, ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).username}!`} </div>
    )
  };
  }
}
export default ReservationsTable;
```

I tried to pay attention to every detail, like not mutating state directly, and all that stuff, but the table data is not getting rendered anyhow, which makes me insane since the data is being available in the state: 
The callback's log after setState:

[Array Log data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZVBg.png)

[Rendered page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3G2D.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a resolution for future readers... 
 The single flaw the code had was the async callback given to the forEach(). As a built-in tool, the forEach mapping is not designed to get asynchronous callbacks, therefore the loop completed before the array got filled and this bypassed the React.JS auto-render when calling setState, since the data entered later into the state object.

Answer (score 0):

The lack of return is the probable cause of this error

```
{ this.state.rows.map((row) => {
  return(
  ...
)}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not this lack of return is causing it. The bigger problem is that every time, regardless of the state data, it renders only the div that states that no data is available...

Comment: put braces {}??

Comment: { this.state.rows.map((row) => {
            return(<TableRow key={row.title}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.title}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.from}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.to}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>)
          }) } like this, right?

Comment: Sorry, but I could not identify the error yet as your data is returned on the console